# Using "apt-get install xxx" inside Python script

Tags: python, apt, apt-get

currently I need to install some package using apt or rpm, according the OS.
I saw the lib "apt" to update or upgrade the system, but it is possible use it to install a single package?

I was trying to use too "subprocess":

```
subprocess.Popen('apt-get install -y filetoinstall', shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, executable="/bin/bash")
```

But this command shows all process in the shell, I cannot hide it.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It seems you are not getting the forked properly. Have you tried reading the documentation?

Comment: For Python 3.5+, see [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `check_call` from the `subprocess` library.

```
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_call
import os
check_call(['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'filetoinstall'],
     stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'), stderr=STDOUT)
```

Dump the `stdout` to `/dev/null`, or `os.devnull` in this case.

`os.devnull` is platform independent, and will return `/dev/null` on POSIX and `nul` on Windows (which is not relevant since you're using `apt-get` but, still good to know :) )

Comment: Thank guys ! I use part of each solution. My code:


    proc = subprocess.Popen('apt-get install -y FILE', shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=open(os.devnull,"wb"), stderr=STDOUT, executable="/bin/bash")
    proc.wait()

Added: stdout and .wait 

Thank you one more time

Comment: This worked for me. I would like to suggest using a try and except block so that in case of an error it will tell you what the issue is rather than just saying there was an error. I added an answer below as a supplement.

Answer (score 5):

Thank guys ! I use part of each solution. My code:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('apt-get install -y FILE', shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=open(os.devnull,"wb"), stderr=STDOUT, executable="/bin/bash")
proc.wait()
```

Added: stdout and .wait

Thank you one more time from Argentina !

Answer (score 3):

For this particular task, as an alternative to `subprocess` you might consider using [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.14/), a python deployment tool to automate builds.

Comment: The link you have shared gives this :

Permission Denied

You don't have the proper permissions to view this page. Please contact the owner of this project to request permission.

Answer (score 2):

This is meant as an addition to Russell Dias's accepted answer. This adds a try and except block to output actionable error information rather than just stating there was an error.

```
from subprocess import check_call, CalledProcessError
import os
try:
    check_call(['apt-get', 'install', '-y', 'filetoinstall'], stdout=open(os.devnull,'wb'))
except CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to redirect the output to /dev/null:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('apt-get install -y filetoinstall', shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=open("/dev/null", "w"), stderr=None, executable="/bin/bash")
proc.wait()
```

The call to .wait() will block until the apt-get is complete.

Comment: Ah ok thanks but how can I stop the program, waiting the apt finish the install, and when is installed , procced with the other functions?

Comment: Thank guys ! I use part of each solution. My code:


    proc = subprocess.Popen('apt-get install -y FILE', shell=True, stdin=None, stdout=open(os.devnull,"wb"), stderr=STDOUT, executable="/bin/bash")
    proc.wait()

Added: stdout and .wait 

Thank you one more time