# install python-mysqldb using python script

Tags: python-2.7

I am writing a python script for an application. The application needs python-mysqldb. In terminal, I can install it with apt-get or pip. How can I install using python script? I am using python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

You could use pip in a python script for installing the package

```
import pip

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pip.main(['install', 'MySQL-python'])
```

Then you can run the script from a terminal.

Comment: This is equivalent to pip install python-mysqldb?

Comment: Yes it is. Of course you need pip installed on the machine ;)

Comment: This is giving error.So I treid adding
'if __name__ == '__main__':
    pip.main(['install','libmysqlclient-dev'])'. This gave error too. So I treid 
'if __name__ == '__main__':
    pip.main(['install','mysql-connector-python'])'. This is giving error too.._Downloading/unpacking mysql-connector-python
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mysql-connector-python
  Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external mysql-connector-python to allow)_

Comment: So actually, the package you mentioned was not the pip name of the package, I changed it to 'MySQL-python'.

Comment: Yes..tried MySQL-python. It said mysql_config not found. So searched web and it said to __apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev__.tried  `if __name__ == __main__: pip.main(['install','libmysqlclient-dev'])`. then tried `if __name__ == '__main__':
    pip.main(['install',mysql-connector-python ''])`.again error _Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement mysql-connector-python Some externally hosted files were ignored (use --allow-external mysql-connector-python to allow)_

Comment: Okay, I've found following answer regarding apt-get in python, maybe it helps :)

[Answer to apt-get](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8482033/4760822)